# Loop within a loop in PowerShell with custom message

Tags: powershell

I am creating a simple test-connection application in which a list of IPs are being pinged. 
The message of the result is based on a list of the hosts(compA, compB, compC, etc).

Currently, i have this code:

```css
FOR %%i IN (
     192.168.200.1
     192.168.200.2
) DO (
     PowerShell -NoProfile -Command "If (Test-Connection %%i -Count 1 -Quiet) { Write-Host "%%i %%hostname - successfully pinged" -F Green } else { Write-Host "%%i %%hostname FAILED" -F Red}
)
```

I want create another loop in which the %%hostname variable is being stored, and will be displayed in the message that corresponds to their specific IP address.

Comment: Why not use ping instead..it's much faster and it work well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution, all in Powershell:

```powershell
$computers = @{"host1"="10.10.10.1";"host2"="10.10.10.200"}

foreach($computer in $computers.getEnumerator()){
    $ip = [string]$computer.Value
    $name = [string]$computer.Name
    If (Test-Connection $ip -Count 1 -Quiet){
        Write-Host ( $name + "- successfully pinged")-F Green 
    }
    else{
        Write-Host ($name + " FAILED") -F Red
    }
}
```